# Object spread operator throw error in microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, object, microsoft-edge, spread-syntax

I have code:

```
let a = {a: 'a', b: 'b'};
let b = {c: 'c', d: 'd'};
let c = {...a, ...b};
```

In **chrome**/**firefox**/... its display: `c = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd'}`, but in **microsoft edge** it throw error `Expected identifier, string or number`.

I try to use `cdn.polyfill.io` and `https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill` but no luck.

What i can do to run my **webpack** code in **microsoft edge**?

Comment: Are you using babel ? If yes, can your post your babel config ?

Comment: Please check the compatibility version from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Kornflexx, i dont use babel to compile my code but i find some post that you can include babel polifyls as script, and because of that i try to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{ ...obj }` syntax is called "[Object Rest/Spread Properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread)" and it's a part of ECMAScript 2018 which is not supported by Edge Legacy. You can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread#spread-properties) to transpile it.

If you just want to use it in non Node.js environments, you can use **babel-standalone**. You just need to load the **babel-standalone** in your script and write the script you want to transpile in script tag with type **“text/babel”** or **“text/jsx”**, the result in Edge Legacy will be `{"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c","d":"d"}`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.18.1/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/babel">
        let a = { a: 'a', b: 'b' };
        let b = { c: 'c', d: 'd' };
        let c = { ...a, ...b };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(c));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

It should be available in Edge since 79 without any transcompiler (like Babel) needed (but not IE, don't confuse them).

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_spread_spread_in_object_literals

That said you could in most situations just use `Object.assign()` instead if you want -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Your code would then be:

```js
let a = {a: 'a', b: 'b'};
let b = {c: 'c', d: 'd'};
let c = Object.assign(a,b)

console.log(c)
```

`Object.assign()` is supported since Edge 12:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_object_assign

Comment: Alex L, my version is `Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0` `Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363`, default instaled on sistem

Comment: Perfect, then you can use ``Object.assign()`` no problem, it is supported since Edge 12:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_object_assign