# Vue JS render error on IE / Microsoft Edge

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, npm, microsoft-edge

The page is loading correctly on every browser except IE 11 and Microsoft Edge. The only error that i can see is "SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
chunk-vendors.8615b873.js (1407,41419)".
The code:

```
this.form.addEventListener("submit",async e=>{
try{
this.$emit("loading",!0),e.preventDefault();
const{
,error:n
}=await this.$stripe.createToken({...this.card,amount:1e3});
```

Comment: For IE 11 you should use babel and configure it to transform async/await, '...' operator and arrow function as a minimum. You can check if something is working in IE11 on caniuse.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the error point to the line using `{ ...obj }` [object rest/spread properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread)? The syntax is a part of ECMAScript 2018 which is not supported by Edge Legacy and IE. You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60651462/object-spread-operator-trow-error-in-microsoft-edge) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417760/react-cant-deconstruct-restprops-in-edge/60430889#60430889) which have similar issues.

You need to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread) to transpile it. Install **@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread** by running:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
```

Then include it as plugin according to the [usage](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread#usage).